# Cakephp 3.0 - using Chronos and datetimepicker, how to input a date without time?

Tags: cakephp-3.0, datetimepicker

In my Cakephp3.0 app, I use Chronos and datetimepicker.

In my Entity file, I have:

> - @property \Cake\I18n\Time $purchase_date

In my Table, I put this:

```
    use Cake\ORM\Query;
    use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
    use Cake\ORM\Table;
    use Cake\Validation\Validator;
```

Then for the Validator:

```
    $validator
       ->date('purchase_date', ['mdy'])
       ->allowEmpty('purchase_date');
```

In edit.ctp, I put this:

```
     <?= $this->Form->input('purchase_date', ['empty' => true]) ?>
```

When I click on the glyphicon-calendar button, I keep getting a value including the time, like : "10/17/2017, 01:58 PM".

What should I do to input only Date in this format: "10/17/2017" ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your database, is your `purchase_date` column a date or datetime? From the property definition, it seems maybe the latter, in which case perhaps you should change the schema so that it's only a date. That way, Cake's auto-determination of the format based on the type will work correctly.

Comment: Thanks alot. Actually it was declared as datetime. and after changing it to date, I got the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of:

```
     <?= $this->Form->input('purchase_date', ['empty' => true]) ?>
```

This code worked for me:

```
     <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'><?= $this->Form->input('purchase_date', ['format' => 'mdy', 'empty' => true]) ?></div>
```